# Why DisplayPort, HDMI port etc. while USB can do the job?

Tags: hdmi, port, external-display, displayport, usb-c

I've been using HP EliteDisplay E232 connected to my hp notebook HP ZBook 15 G2 through DisplayPort for some time now. Both the monitor and the notebook has Full HD 1920X1080 resolution. I was so glad that I changed to DisplayPort from VGA cable because the display now looks much better and crisp through DP.

I recently started using "HP port replicator 3005pr" for ease of connecting multiple devices to the notebook. Now I can connect headset, mic, network, keyboard, mouse, display etc. to the notebook through a  single usb connector.

notebook -> usb -> port replicator -> other devices through their own ports

It's very easy and awesome. Interestingly I am finding the display as good and crisp as though the monitor is directly connected to the DisplayPort of notebook.

Now coming to the question - The video signal from my notebook is going out through the USB port. That means it *can* transfer good data/signal. If USB can transfer/deliver signal as high quality as the DisplayPort then why DisplayPort? Why invent all these multitudes of port specifications (HDMI, Display, Firewire etc.) and their versions? Why not every device come with a USB port and be super compatible with every other device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI, DP, and VGA are media connections, where USB is a data connection.

USB doesn't transfer actual video/audio signals, just the data that they can be produced from.

Your dock has a USB video adapter in it that actually processes the data coming in via USB into video, mostly via software, using the computer's CPU to process (most of) the data.  The adapter in the dock was provided by [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/), ([DL3900 chip apparently](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/buying-advice/pc-peripheral/hp-3005pr-usb-30-port-replicator-review-3413173/)).

The odds are your dock has resolution limits that are lower then if you hooked the same display(s) directly to video ports on the laptop itself (can't check for sure, as you didn't supply the laptop's model).

Here's a note from your dock's support pages:

> Two external displays with 1920 x 1200 resolution each are available
>   when connected through a USB 3.0 connection from the notebook to the
>   port replicator. Up to a 2560 x 1600 resolution is available on a
>   single external display connected through a USB 3.0 connection from
>   the notebook to the port replicator, however when a 2560 x 1600
>   resolution display is connected to the port replicator, the unused
>   port will be disabled.

If your not using the dock, and your system happens to have a discrete (aka "[dedicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_card#Dedicated_vs_integrated_graphics)") video adapter (like an AMD or NVidia adapter), then *it* will process the video in its GPU, reducing/removing the CPU power required to process data into a video signal.

This would be especially noticeable in 3D applications/games, and full screen HD video playback, where the video adapter often plays a large part in the processing by off-loading from the CPU.  This leaves the CPU free to process other data without interrupting the video processing, as well as performing tasks that help accelerate video by processing tasks the GPU may no be able to do, like decoding a video file format that has no hardware decoder.

Aside from processing power and off-loading, there's also bandwidth differences for the data being transferred to and from the video adapter.

Since this data all needs to be jammed down a single USB3.0 port for this dock, even at it's theoretical maximum of about 640 MBps (which you'll never get), you'd notice it even more when you start hooking other devices (flash drives, audio devices, network connectivity, etc.) into the dock, as they all have to share that single pipe.

To compare, a PCI Express ([PCIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)) (v1.0) 1x connection is ~250MBps (theoretical max.), and PCIe (v1.0) 16x connection is ~1GBps.

Most current discrete video adapters use more than a single PCIe 1x lane, and use newer revisions of the PCIe spec, which are faster.

For example, the latest PCIe version 3, it's basically 1GBps, per PCIe lane.

- PCIe 1x = ~1GBps
- PCIe 4x = ~4GBps
- PCIe 16x = ~16GBps

So a current video adapter, using a single PCIe 1x v3.0 connection is going to pass almost twice as much data, except it will be utilized for transferring *only* video (and maybe audio) data utilized by the video adapter.

Comparing to an integrated video adapter (i.e.: an Intel GMA/HD video adapter that's part of a Intel CPU) is a similar story.  While integrated adapters use the CPU for the majority of their processing, they have dedicated parts of the CPU for certain aspects of the video processing (hardware decoders and alike).

Although, like the USB DisplayLink adapter, they also use the CPU for processing, they have a distinct advantage of being tightly coupled to the CPU itself, which is tightly coupled to RAM. This tight coupling allows for much higher bandwidth and lower latency between the components, allowing them to perform at admirable levels.

Comment: I wasn't considering the data transfer capacity and other distinct features of each port. Thanks for the quick summary.

Comment: Another issue is that HDMI, VGA, etc. are designed to provide a single dedicated path to stream video at a steady rate without disturbances.  For a variety of reasons, USB cannot always accomplish that reliably.  If one were sending video in real time over USB, the display would likely glitch or stutter when accessing other USB devices.

Answer (score 4):

The profusion of interfaces largely comes down to the timing of developments.

USB, as its name says, is a *universal* interface and was developed to allow the interchange of multiple types of digital traffic, and the original USB1 standard was a break-though.

However, when people wanted to connect AV devices, the higher data rates were beyond the then USB specification, so FireWire was invented, which was also fast enough for disc interfacing and other high-speed traffic.

Then USB2 was established, but not before there was a large investment in Firewire devices, and it was a long time before USB2 became the interface of choice for high-speed data transfer.

The FireWire lobby then doubled the speed with the FW800 specification, but USB2 was by now too established for FW800 to compete, and USB3 has become more or less unopposed as a universal interface for general, high-speed data transfer. Of course, this is not fast enough for the fastest internal discs, and these use their own SATA interface, specifically for this purpose.

While all this was going on, developments were needed to replace analogue displays by digital ones, and CPUs were not fast enough to use USB, so a specific digital interface (DisplayPort) was developed to do this directly on video cards. At the same time, TV and video recorders and players needed a fast AV digital interface, and HDMI was developed for this: now that these all use HDMI, there is no incentive for AV equipment manufacturers to use USB instead.

Meanwhile, Apple went their own way and established standards which were readily adopted in their own products, but have little currency outside.

This is a very gross simplification of how developments have occurred over the years, but I hope it goes some way to illustrate how interfaces have proliferated. If there were any trend to concentrate on USB, it is certain that newer interfaces with their own advantages will have appeared before any uniformity is established.

As a final observation, 3D video and UHD are now established over HDMI: I doubt if your port replicator handles these, so the leap-frogging will continue.

Comment: Thank you for the profound summary and the short history.

> The profusion of interfaces largely comes down to the timing of developments.

It actually points to the fact that all port specifications didn't start together on a fine day. Evolution of ports. I was not considering that point. By the way,  I don't have enough reputation to upvote, sorry.

Comment: I was trying to answer your question about why USB is not used everywhere, rather than comparing specific interfaces. I'm glad my contribution was useful.